# Creating a correlation matrix from a data frame in R

Tags: r, matrix, correlation

I have a data frame of correlations which looks something like this (although there are ~15,000 rows in my real data)

```
phen1<-c("A","B","C")
phen2<-c("B","C","A")
cors<-c(0.3,0.7,0.8)

data<-as.data.frame(cbind(phen1, phen2, cors))

    phen1  phen2   cors
1     A      B      0.3
2     B      C      0.7
3     C      A      0.8
```

This was created externally and read into R and I want to convert this data frame into a correlation matrix with phen1 and 2 as the labels for rows and columns of this matrix. I have only calculated this for either the lower or upper triangle and I don't have the 1's for the Diagnonal. So I would like the end results to be a full correlation matrix but a first step would probably be to create the lower/upper triangle and then convert to a full matrix I think. I'm unsure how to do either step of this.

Also, the results may not be in an intuitive order, but I'm not sure if this matters, but ideally I would like a way to do this which uses the labels in phen1 and phen 2 to make sure the matrix has the correct values in the correct place if that makes sense?

Essentially for this, I would want something like this as an end result:

```
  A    B    C
A 1    0.3  0.8
B 0.3  1    0.7
C 0.8  0.7  1
```

Comment: Do not use `cbind` there. It coerces the numbers to character strings. Just do `data <- data.frame(phen1, phen2, cors)`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another one in base R where we create a symmetrical dataframe same as `data` but with columns inverted for `phen1` and `phen2`. Then we use `xtabs` to get a correlation matrix and set diagonal to 1.

```
data1 <- data.frame(phen1 = data$phen2, phen2 = data$phen1, cors = data$cors)  
df <- rbind(data, data1)
df1 <- as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(cors ~ ., df))
diag(df1) <- 1
df1

#    A   B   C
#A 1.0 0.3 0.8
#B 0.3 1.0 0.7
#C 0.8 0.7 1.0
```

**data**

```
phen1<-c("A","B","C")
phen2<-c("B","C","A")
cors<-c(0.3,0.7,0.8)
data<- data.frame(phen1, phen2, cors)
```

Comment: Ah that's the one I was looking for: A solution with `xtabs`. Nice job +1. It's interesting that with OPs `data` definition (where `data$cors` is a `factor`) `xtabs` doesn't work and throws an error. That's where I got stuck...

Answer (score 3):

I think there must be an elegant way to do it, however, here is a `dplyr` and `tidyr` possibility:

```
data %>%
 spread(phen1, cors) %>%
 rename(phen = "phen2") %>%
 bind_rows(data %>%
            spread(phen2, cors) %>%
            rename(phen = "phen1")) %>%
 group_by(phen) %>%
 summarise_all(~ ifelse(all(is.na(.)), 1, first(na.omit(.))))

  phen      A     B     C
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A       1     0.3   0.8
2 B       0.3   1     0.7
3 C       0.8   0.7   1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Matrix package for this. What you have is a sparse representation of the data and you want to turn this into a dense (redundant) matrix.

```
data <- data.frame(phen1, phen2, cors)

inds <- cbind(as.integer(data$phen1), as.integer(data$phen2))
inds <- t(apply(inds, 1, sort))

library(Matrix)
res <- sparseMatrix(i = inds[,1], 
             j = inds[,2], 
             x = data$cors,
             symmetric = TRUE)
#3 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dsCMatrix"
#
#[1,] .   0.3 0.8
#[2,] 0.3 .   0.7
#[3,] 0.8 0.7 . 

res <- as.matrix(res)
diag(res) <- 1
dimnames(res) <- list(sort(data$phen1), sort(data$phen2))
res
#    A   B   C
#A 1.0 0.3 0.8
#B 0.3 1.0 0.7
#C 0.8 0.7 1.0
```

Comment: why is the as.integer() there in the part creating inds? The values within these columns are all strings, so that part throws a warning about NAs being introdcued by coercion

Comment: I'm assuming that they are factors (which they should be if you created a standard data.frame and didn't set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`).

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option.

First reshape data from long to wide and convert to a `matrix`. You have different options to do that (`reshape2`, `tidyr`, etc.); here I use `tidyr::spread`.

```
library(tidyverse)
mat <- data %>% spread(phen2, cors) %>% column_to_rownames("phen1") %>% as.matrix()
```

We then fill the missing `NA` values from the upper and lower triangular matrix respectively, and fill the diagonal with `1`.

```
mat[lower.tri(mat)] <- mapply(sum, mat[lower.tri(mat)], mat[upper.tri(mat)], na.rm = T)
mat[upper.tri(mat)] <- mat[lower.tri(mat)]
diag(mat) <- 1
mat
#    A   B   C
#A 1.0 0.3 0.8
#B 0.3 1.0 0.7
#C 0.8 0.7 1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reshape library.

```
library(reshape)
data <- melt(data)
your_mat <- cast(data, phen1 ~ phen2 )
```

Output:

```
  phen1    A    B    C
1     A <NA>  0.3 <NA>
2     B <NA> <NA>  0.7
3     C  0.8 <NA> <NA>
```

The reason you will NAs because you have many missing combination from your input table. For avoiding this you need an input table like this:

```
  phen1 phen2 cors
1     A     B  0.3
2     B     C  0.7
3     C     A  0.8
4     A     C  0.8
5     B     A  0.3
6     C     B  0.7
7     A     A  1.0
8     B     B  1.0
9     C     C  1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of solutions already, but I'll throw in another way. Note: I'm setting up the data so that `cors` is numeric rather than a factor in your original data frame.

```
data <- data.frame(phen1, phen2, cors)
```

Then we can expand the data frame with missing combinations and then uses `reshape2::acast()` to convert the data to wide format.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)

data %>% 
  select(phen1 = phen2, phen2 = phen1, cors) %>%
  bind_rows(data) %>%
  acast(phen1 ~ phen2, fill = 1)
```

`acast` handily lets you fill in the missing values with some other specified value, in this case 1.

Also, check out the `corrr` package, which may be able to do this more neatly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that I wrote:

```
long2cormat <- function(xlong, x = "x", y = "y", r = "r") {
    # Takes some inspiration from https://stackoverflow.com/a/57904948/180892
    xlong <- xlong[,c(x, y, r)]
    names(xlong) <- c("x", "y", "r")
    
    data1 <- data.frame(x = xlong$x, y = xlong$y, r = xlong$r)    
    data2 <- data.frame(x = xlong$y, y = xlong$x, r = xlong$r)  
    df <- rbind(data1, data2)
    
    uv <- unique(c(df$x, df$y))
    df1 <- matrix(NA, nrow = length(uv), ncol = length(uv), dimnames = list(uv, uv))
    for (i in seq(nrow(df))) df1[df$x[i], df$y[i]] <- df$r[i]
    diag(df1) <- 1
    df1
}
```

To run it do the following:

```
xlong <- data.frame(phen1 = c("A","B","C"),
    phen2 = c("B","C","A"),
    cors = c(0.3,0.7,0.8))
long2cormat(xlong, "phen1", "phen2", "cors")
```

Importantly, for my own use cases, it leaves missing correlations as NA.

Comment: You could get more efficiency by leaving out the loop and using a two-column character matrix for indexing on the LHS for the assignment of the entire vector of correlations: `df1[ data.matrix(df[,-3]) ] <- df[,3]`